# Preact CLI How To Access Index Page

Tags: javascript, node.js, terminal, preact

I have created an app using the preact-cli, like so:

```
preact create <template-name> <app-name>
```

But there is no "index" page, and I can't see any worker scripts or build folders. So I was wandering how I can access these, so I can for example change the title of the Page...

By the way the folder created looks like this:

```
> app-name
    > /node_modules
    > /src
        > /components
        > /routes
        > /style
        > index.js
        > manifest.json
    > .gitignore
    > package-lock.json
    > package.json
    > README.md
```

Comment: why not simply use document.title in your root level component to change the tilte of the page ?

Comment: Thats not the point of this question. I would rather have access to the index page etc. to have more control of ssr and stuff

Answer (score 1):

Source: https://github.com/developit/preact-cli#template

**If you want to customise your template you can pass a custom template with the --template flag.**

```
preact build --template src/template.html
preact watch --template src/template.html
```